# Что такое row для scrop slota и для чего он нужен?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Не могу найти про это информацию, где про это можно прочитать? Просто scope не работает в моем случает, только с row.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: а что за тема?.

Comment: `scope` - это данные, которые были переданы из компонента, в котором отрисовывается слот. В Вашем случае, видимо, в этих данных содержиться объект, у которого есть поле `row`, у которого есть поле `name` и `gender`

Answer (score 0):

`slot-scope` это устаревший синтаксис директивы `v-slot`. Если вы используете vue 3, то он оттуда уже удален и поэтому может не работать. Почитать можете [на странице официальной документации vue 2](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html#%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%8B-%D1%81-%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%89%D1%8C%D1%8E-%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B1%D1%83%D1%82%D0%B0-slot-scope)
`row` в свою очередь это переданное поле через `slot-scope` объекта `scope`